# Private endpoint for Redis Cache

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

Azure provides a feature to many PaaS services called as Private endpoint. I know it is not available for all services but is it available for Azure Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Redis actually is in "Private Preview" for this feature, meaning that we are letting a subset of customers have access to the feature to kick the tires, give us feedback, verify quality, etc.  Public preview is expected late this summer or early fall.  If you are interested in trying out the private preview, please file a support ticket with customer support and we can give you access.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Private Link enables you to access Azure PaaS Services and Azure-hosted customer-owned/partner services over a private endpoint in your virtual network. Azure Private Link for Azure Cache for Redis provides private connectivity from a virtual network to your cache instance. This means that you can now use Azure Private Link to connect to an Azure Cache for Redis instance from your virtual network via a private endpoint, which is assigned a private IP address in a subnet within the virtual network. It simplifies the network architecture and secures the connection between endpoints in Azure by eliminating data exposure to the public internet. Private Link carries traffic privately, reducing your exposure to threats and helps you meet compliance standards.

Do check out this tutorial https://developer.redislabs.com/create/azure/terraform-private-endpoint